# how do i change the font color of current link

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_item" style="overflow:visible;">
      <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="./About_us.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="./contact_us.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="./feedback.php">YOUR FEEDBACK</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>

</div>
```

How to change the current link's font color (lets say if I opened "About_us.php")?

Comment: Where / how exactly are you trying to use `a:active`? How do you know that it "doesn't work"? It seems you forgot to post your CSS.

Comment: div#nav_item ul {height: auto; padding: 8px 0px;margin: 0px;}
div#nav_item li { display: inline; padding: 20px; }
div#nav_item a {text-decoration: none;color: #006633;padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;}
div#nav_item a:hover {color: #F90;}

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add your CSS and explain properly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
a:active
{ 
   color:yellow;
}
/* for visited */
a:visited { 

   color: red;

}
```

```html
<div id="nav_item" style="overflow:visible;">
      <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./About_us.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="./About_us.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="./contact_us.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="./feedback.php">YOUR FEEDBACK</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're using a general menu file for every site, or do you have this menu hard-coded in every page you have there, but if the menu is coded to every page separately:

You could use `.active` CSS class instead of the `:active` selector. For what I know it requires some configuration for the website to recognize on what page you are in, or at least I haven't got it to work in my old projects back when I didn't use a framework around my page.

CSS:

```
.active {
   color: #ff0000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_item" style="overflow:visible;">
  <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./About_us.php" class="active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="./About_us.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="./contact_us.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="./feedback.php">YOUR FEEDBACK</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And after these are all set up, you can change the `class` function elsewhere, to another page. This example would work when you're on the front page. Just move the class to another link in another page.

It's an easy way to do it, though it's not an easy way to build a website in general.

Comment: this is my css: div#nav_item ul {height: auto; padding: 8px 0px;margin: 0px;}
div#nav_item li { display: inline; padding: 20px; }
div#nav_item a {text-decoration: none;color: #006633;padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;}
div#nav_item a:hover {color: #F90;}

Answer (score 0):

```
   a:active
    {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/s3mqt3fj/)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. :active is a selector which is triggered when a click is detected by css. If you apply styles to :active selector, those styles will be visible when you click the object. (Try clicking and holding, then you will see the styles you have applied)

To highlight the current page, what you need to do is add a class to the current page and add your custom styles to that class. See this demo.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYYWjM

HTML Should be like this

```
<a href="#">Click here and hold to see the :active<a>
<br><br>
<a class="active" href="#">This is blue by default</a>
```

And CSS

```
a:active {color: red;}
a.active {color: blue;}
```

PS - And NO, there is no shortcut. The class has to be added. And you'll have to figure out something to add the class automatically :)
Since you have asked this, You better try w3schools, codeacadamy, etc to improve your knowledge. You will find some good tutorials online.

Comment: <style>
    div#nav_item ul {height: auto;padding: 8px 0px;margin: 0px;} 
    div#nav_item li {display: inline;padding: 20px;}
    div#nav_item a {text-decoration: none;color: #006633;padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;}
    div#nav_item a:hover {color: #F90;}   (this is my css)